# Excel VBA - Add word after pasting

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add the word "Model" after pasting data, and I thought I could just put `& " Model"` after the paste, so it'd be "Paste what you find and (add) Model", but I get debug error:

[image]

Am I not using the right paste type?

Here's the code, if needed:

```
If Model.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Model.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues & " Model"
    Model.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Else
    Model.Columns(1).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues & " Model"
    Model.Columns(2).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If
```

The 2nd copy/paste is just for numbers, nothing needs added there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're using `.PasteSpecial`, then this has to be two steps; you can't both paste and append data in one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
.Cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues & " Model"
```

you'll need to do something like

```
.Cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Cells(n + 1, "E").Value = .Cells(n + 1, "E").Value & " Model"
```

Comment: Got it... thank you!